# i can't print all the print

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

so I have code to convert a words .txt (300000 word) to a list but the  terminal is deleting some parts and can't read it, so can I print this to a .txt or print a % of the print .

this is the code to convert .txt to a list:

```
def load_words():
    with open('words_alpha.txt') as word_file:
        valid_words = set(word_file.read().split())

    return valid_words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    english_words = load_words()
    print(english_words)
```

Comment: Start with a *much* smaller file. What is the contents of that (small) file? What is the expected output of the shown code? What is the actual output?

Comment: Which shell are you using? If a unix shell, you could run `python3 your_script | less` and be able to scroll the output (`q` to quit). To output to a file use `>`: `python3 your_script >new_file.txt` (careful **this will overwrite the output file if existing**)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify with one function and it should theoretically work. If it doesn’t work for 300000 word try first a smaller file.

```
def countWordsInFile():

    array = []
    fileName = getUserText("Enter the name of the file you want to read array from")
    openFile = openNewFile(fileName,"read")
    i = openFile
    for words in i.read().split():
        for word in words:
            array.append(word)

    print(array)
```

Comment: yeah i will definitely use a smaller file . it was dump to use that a 300000 word